# How to downgrade and upgrade azure virtual machine programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am using about 40 virtual machines in azure. Their sizes are all Standard B4ms which has 4 CPUs and 16GB RAM.
They are being used for scraping. And while they are not being used, I would like to downgrade their sizes a little so that they cost little.
Is it possible to downgrade azure vm sizes programmatically?
Azure has restful apis to downgrade the vm size?

Comment: [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dtl/virtualmachines/resize) was the second result on Google for “azure vm resize api” - please research and attempt to solve the problem before posting here in accordance with the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: No, that's for devtest lab. I don't use devtest lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call the rest API below to resize your VM:

**Request URL:**

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vm name>?api-version=2020-12-01
```

**Request Header:**

```
Authorization: Bearer <access token>
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Request Body**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "<vm size, i,e: Standard_B1s>"
        }
    },
    "location": "<vm location, i,e:East US>"
}
```

Before call this API :
[image]

Call this API:
[image]

After :
[image]

Pls note that resizing VMS will restart VMS and this operation will fail if your VM enables some functionality that lower VM size not available.

Comment: How to get oauth token? Do you have any online reference for that?

Comment: I mean azure token. To send resize vm request, I need to get oauth token. How to get it?

Comment: @FrancescoTagliani, just see this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#acquire-an-access-token

Comment: Do you have skype?

Comment: @FrancescoTagliani, no, if you have any questions, just post another question and let know the link

Comment: I've got oauth token and send resize request but get following error

Comment: ```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client 'a801ead3-1879-4efb-a468-6cd716ca2669' with object id 'a801ead3-1879-4efb-a468-6cd716ca2669' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resize/write' over scope '/subscriptions/25750a87-75be-487a-840f-14612b6f9c15/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ApiSearch1' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
    }
}
```

Comment: @FrancescoTagliani, this is a permission error, your azure ad object have no permission to do that. details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview

Comment: Where should I go and add permission to azure ad object?

Comment: Yes, you should do that

Comment: In which page? Can you send me the link?

Comment: Just follow this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal. You can assign owner or contributor role for a quick test